# why do change inputs and outputs of functions in dll?

Tags: matlab

I have Sum.m and Multiplication.m

They have two inputs (double) and one output (double).

```
function z=Sum(x,y)
z=x+y;
end 

function z=Subtraction(x,y)
z=x-y;
end
```

I have mylib.dll with

```
mcc -t -L C -W lib:mylib -T link:lib Sum.m Subtraction.m libmmfile.mlib
```

I can see my functions with

```
libfunctionsview('mylib')
```

I run this:

```
calllib('mylib','Subtraction', 10, 20);
```

I get:

```
??? Error using ==> calllib
Method was not found.
```

I run this:

```
calllib('mylib','mlxSubtraction', 10, 20);
```

and

```
??? Error using ==> calllib
No method with matching signature
```

Edited: I use this code, but output is zero. why?

```
z=[];  
calllib('mylib','mlfSum', 1, z, 10, 20);  
ans=0
```

I want a dll file from Sum.m and Subtraction.m. I want to use tihs dll file in matlab program. Why must i use 4 argumants in mu function?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Subtraction` instead of `Multiplication`?

Comment: I edit it. However I have these Errors. Subtraction changes to mlxSubtraction and number of argumants become more.